# Postgres: Is Date between now and interval for EVERY birthday

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I want to be able to return Users who have a birthday between now and a specified time interval.

**User Model**

- name (string)
- birthday (date)

**My Time Interval** = 30 days

**My Data Set**

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      id             |     name         |     birthday     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        Tim       |   27/06/1994     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

**My Attempt**

```
SELECT * FROM User where User.birthday BETWEEN NOW()::timestamp AND to_char(NOW() + interval '30 days','MM-DD')::timestamp;
```

**Returns**

Empty. Postgres is assuming that by omitting the year I actually mean year 1.

**What I want**

This query to return all users whose birthday resides in the interval regardless of the year.

**Attempt From Answers (Many thanks @Mureinik)**

```
SELECT *
FROM   user
WHERE  birthday BETWEEN TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'MM-DD') AND
TO_CHAR(NOW() + INTERVAL '30 days','MM-DD')
```

**Issues with this answer**

- This will not work if 30 days from now is next year.
- If the year is a leap year, will this interval not need to be 31 days?

Comment: Tim's birthday was in 1994. Really all you care about is the day and the month for the comparison, not the date.

Comment: Regarding your second issue about interval to be 30 or 31 days, you can just specify that the interval is '1 month'

Comment: @KamilG. That would be fine if the desired interval was 1 month and not 30 days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generated a new date based on the current year and the user's birthday month and day, then see if that is in the next 30 days.

```
select *
from user
where date(date_part('year', current_date)||'-'||date_part('month', birthday)||'-'||date_part('day', birthday))
    between current_date and current_date + interval '30 days';
```

For example:

```
# select * from user;
 id | name  |  birthday
----+-------+------------
  1 | Tim   | 1994-06-27
  2 | Steve | 1982-06-23
  3 | Dave  | 1980-07-29
(3 rows)

# select *
from user
where date(date_part('year', current_date)||'-'||date_part('month', birthday)||'-'||date_part('day', birthday))
    between current_date and current_date + interval '30 days';
 id | name  |  birthday
----+-------+------------
  1 | Tim   | 1994-06-27
  2 | Steve | 1982-06-23
(2 rows)
```

Comment: That doesn't work if current_date + 30 days is the next year

Comment: @MaicolBen I believe it would. The `+interval '30 days'` should calculate the future date just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert both the `between`'s arguments to strings and use lexicographical comparison. Since the format is fixed-width, this should be OK:

```
SELECT *
FROM   user
WHERE  birthday BETWEEN TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'MM-DD') AND
                        TO_CHAR(NOW() + INTERVAL '30 days','MM-DD')
```

Comment: This is a good start, but fails if 30 days from now is next year.

Answer (score 0):

Here, what I implemented in my project with QueryDsl support:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DTF_MM_dd = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd");

protected BooleanExpression betweenLocalDatesIgnoringYear(DatePath<LocalDate> localDate, LocalDate from, LocalDate to) {
    if (from == null && to == null) {
        return Expressions.asBoolean(true).isTrue();
    }
    if (Objects.equals(from, to)) {
        return eqLocalDateIgnoringYear(localDate, from);
    }
    Set<String> MM_DDs = new HashSet<>();
    for (LocalDate date = (from != null ? from : LocalDate.now());
         date.isBefore(to != null ? to.plusDays(1) : from.plusMonths(1).plusDays(1));
         date = date.plusDays(1)) {

        MM_DDs.add(DTF_MM_dd.format(date));
    }
    if (MM_DDs.contains("02-28")) {
        MM_DDs.add("02-29");
    }
    if (MM_DDs.isEmpty()) {
        return Expressions.asBoolean(true).isTrue();
    }
    return localDateIgnoringYearIn(localDate, MM_DDs.stream().toArray(String[]::new));
}

protected BooleanExpression eqLocalDateIgnoringYear(DatePath<LocalDate> pathLocalDate, LocalDate localDate) {
    if (localDate == null) {
        return Expressions.asBoolean(true).isTrue();
    }
    return localDateIgnoringYearIn(pathLocalDate, DTF_MM_dd.format(localDate));
}

private BooleanExpression localDateIgnoringYearIn(DatePath<LocalDate> pathLocalDate, String... values) {
    return Expressions.stringTemplate("FUNCTION('to_char', {0},'MM-DD')", pathLocalDate).in(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% the same, but if you just need to calculate the number of days until the next anniversary, and you're ok ignoring leap years, you can do some math using the date of the year (`DOY`) and modulo functions. e.g.

```
select (EXTRACT(DOY FROM birthday) - EXTRACT(DOY FROM NOW()) + 365)::integer % 365 from user;
```

This works by forcing the difference between them to be positive and future looking by adding 365, and then removing anything extra to just get the remainder using the modulo